Meaning of ぐれー in this sentence

スカしっぺでも響き渡るぐれ〜
静かな場所になっちまったよ！

In this sentence, is ぐれー another way of saying ぐらい？

Yes, this is a typical example of the /ai/-to-/ee/ contraction. It sounds slangy, masculine, and a little rough. For details, please see the following questions:

What does こまけー mean?
わからない vs わかね in My Boss My Hero
Changing of vowels at the end of words to え
What is じゃねぇか? What is its original form?

